Unable to load a Website due to SSL certificate authentication using Selenium for Automation
I am using Selenium for running an Automation script in a Chrome Browser , to load a webpage . However the VPN certificate needs to be clicked okay for the expected webpage to load I have tried using Chrome options
The ones listed below but none of them is allowing me to accept or Bypass the Certificate
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true)
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

Any suggestions would be of great help.
thanks

Clicking to accept the cert in a manual session should add it to your OS's cert store.  Have you ever done that?  (I'm assuming this is a VPN you trust and they are using a self-signed cert)
